# free() for 2D malloc array not freeing memory?

Tags: pointers, memory, malloc, free, allocation

I am drafting a code from WSL1 and I am scratching the back of my head because I have a very confusing problem.

First, I allocate ~10 GB of RAM using malloc

```
int** megaarray;
megaarray=(int**)malloc( x*sizeof(int*) * y * count );

    for(int i=0; i<x * count; i++){ // x = 3200, count =1000, both integers
    megaarray[i]=(int*)malloc(y*sizeof(int) ); // y = 4200, integer
 }
```

Allocation goes well, and I use that segment of RAM, then at the end of some computing I try to de-allocate:

```
 for(int i=0; i<x * count; i++){ // x = 3200, count =1000, both integers
    free(megaarray[i]);
 }
free(megaarray);
```

I kept on getting a crash when the same function using the above is used the second time and I put a sleeper in between each allocation/de-allocation to find that de-allocation is simply not happening! What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Such a weird behaviour, on WSL1, when count is 1000, free-ing doesn't quite work and code crashes.

On Full Linux x64 machine, freeing works from sampling, but the code crashes right away.

On WSL1, when count is brought down to 715, code works perfectly fine, on Full Linux, code runs perfectly but if and only if the count is brought down to 600.

I am guessing this has to do with buffer and max RAM allowed per application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue, it is the dumbest part on my side. I initialized to the wrong mallocation size:

```
megaarray=(int**)malloc( x*sizeof(int*) * y * count );
```

is actually 4 bytes times the memory I need. I would have ended up using 4*1000*3200*4200/1000000000 ~= 54GB!

Reducing count to 600: ~31GB, my systems have 32GB,
Reducing count to 715: ~35GB, this should not have worked...

It should be actually:

```
 megaarray=(int**)malloc( x * y * count );
```

and the code works throughout all of the platforms.

By getting rid of the premature integer pointer size declaration, I use ~13GB even with 1000 counts

Now, the questions left standing:

- How did this work at least half of the way on WSL?!
- Why is WSL1 not "freeing" RAM back to Windows when the memory is freed and why is it eating up more RAM instead of the same pre-allocated sections when allocating more RAM?